# How to send SMS on php Textlocal.in api

Tags: php

I have used this code for send OTP on Given number. but can't send SMS. how to solve this....

PHP code

```
<?php
require_once ('smartysettings.php');
require_once ('class/User.php');
require_once ('class/Sms.php');
require_once ('class/RandomNumber.php');

$number = $_POST['mobnum'];

    $result = @User::GetUserIdORMobile($number);

        if($result->database->rows = 1)
        {
            $otp = RandomNumber(10);
            $message = "Your OTP(One Time Password) is '$otp'";
            $sender = 'Minveedu';

            //print_r($otp); exit;

           @Sms::SmsSend($number,$message,$sender);
        }
?>
```

major class file for send SMS
PHP code

```
    <?php
        require_once ('textlocal.class.php');

    class Sms
    {
        var $sms;
        var $textloc;


        public function __construct()
        {
           $this->textloc = new Textlocal('*******************', '****************');
        }


        public static function SmsSend($number,$message,$sender)
        {
            $ins = new self();

            $numbers = array($number);

            return $ins->textloc->sendSms($numbers,$message,$sender);
        }
    }

?>
```

how to solve and send SMS. please help for this request.

Answer (score 0):

they themselves provide the code in php to send sms, you can find it by logging into your account then navigate **HELP >> All DOCUMENTATION >>** here you will find the copy and paste code section. just go through and it will work